# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a simple brick breaker game using Java Script, and my console is showing me error while displaying blocks on to the canvas, they are being drawn onto the canvas but all the other objects are not working and console is showing

> index.js:173 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
> at update (index.js:173)
> at index.js:177

if you comment out from line no:172 and 173, which is a for loop that tells the canvas to draw them on it
everything's is working fine.

> one more thing: that canvasRendering...rundedRectangle is a function that draws rounded edge rectangles
> someone please find a solution!

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundedRectangle = function(x, y, width, height, rounded) {
    const radiansInCircle = 2 * Math.PI
    const halfRadians = (2 * Math.PI)/2
    const quarterRadians = (2 * Math.PI)/4  
    
    // top left arc
    this.arc(rounded + x, rounded + y, rounded, -quarterRadians, halfRadians, true)
    
    // line from top left to bottom left
    this.lineTo(x, y + height - rounded)
  
    // bottom left arc  
    this.arc(rounded + x, height - rounded + y, rounded, halfRadians, quarterRadians, true)  
    
    // line from bottom left to bottom right
    this.lineTo(x + width - rounded, y + height)
  
    // bottom right arc
    this.arc(x + width - rounded, y + height - rounded, rounded, quarterRadians, 0, true)  
    
    // line from bottom right to top right
    this.lineTo(x + width, y + rounded)  
  
    // top right arc
    this.arc(x + width - rounded, y + rounded, rounded, 0, -quarterRadians, true)  
    
    // line from top right to top left
    this.lineTo(x + rounded, y)  
}

var canvas= document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function Player(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.show = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    this.move = function(speed){
        this.x += speed;
    }
}

function Ball(x,y,r){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.show = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2* Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "tomato";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    this.move= function(speedX,speedY){
        this.show();
        this.speed = 2;
        this.x += speedX;
        this.y += speedY;
    }

}

function Block(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.show= function(color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.roundedRectangle(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h,7);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
};

var player = new Player(canvas.width/2-50,canvas.height*0.95,100,20);
var ball = new Ball(canvas.width/2-5, player.y-20,15);
var rigthPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

var blocks = [];
var rowCount = 5;
var columnCount = 6;
var noInRow = 6;
var blockCount = (rowCount*columnCount)+1;
var blockRow = 0;
var blockCol = 0;

var ballSpeedX = 5;
var ballSpeedY = -10;
for(let i = 1; i < blockCount; i++){
    blocks.push(new Block(blockCol*60+25,blockRow*60+30,50,50)); 
    blockCol++;
    if(i % noInRow == 0){
        blockRow++;
        blockCol = 0;
    }
}


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        rigthPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = true;
    }
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        rigthPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = false;
    }
});

function objMovement(){
    if(rigthPressed){
        player.move(5);
        if (player.x > canvas.width-player.w){
            player.x = canvas.width-player.w;
        }
    }
    if(leftPressed){
        player.move(-5);
        if(player.x < 0){
            player.x = 0;
        }
    }

    if(ball.x > canvas.width-ball.r || ball.x < 0+ball.r){
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    }
    if (ball.y > canvas.height-ball.r || ball.y < 0+ball.r){
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }
    if(ball.x<player.x+player.w &&ball.x>player.x && ball.y>player.y){
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        ballSpeedX= ballSpeedX;
    }
    function Bump(){
        if (ball.x>player.x && ball.x<player.x+player.w/2){
            if (ball.y >= player.y){
                ballSpeedX = -5;
            }
        }
        if(ball.x>player.x+player.w/2 && ball.x<player.x+player.w){
            if(ball.y >= player.y){
                ballSpeedX = 5;
            }
        }
    }   
    //Bump();
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ball.show();
    ball.move(ballSpeedX,ballSpeedY);
    player.show();
    objMovement();
    for(let i=0;i<blockCount;i++){
        blocks[i].show("violet");    
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #body{
            background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
        }
        #gameCanvas{
            border: 15px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color:rgb(19, 18, 18);
            margin: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width=400 height=800></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `blocks` you start from 1

```
for (let i = 1; i < blockCount; i++) {
    blocks.push(new Block(blockCol * 60 + 25, blockRow * 60 + 30, 50, 50));
    ...
```

so when you **update** you need to consider that

```
function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ball.show();
    ball.move(ballSpeedX, ballSpeedY);
    player.show();
    objMovement();
    for (let i = 0; i < blockCount -1; i++) { // or for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].show("violet");
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```